# Xcode Exit with Error 254 in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors

First of all, I know that there are many questions on this topic but couldn't find solution for me.

Suddenly,I am getting the clang error like as follow:

```
1.  /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFString.h:154:2: current parser token 'if'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: i386-apple-darwin11.4.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254
```

**I am not able to solve this.**
**Please help me to solve this error..**

Comment: Without seeing the portion of code that *causes* the error, we can't help you.

Comment: @middaparka, Thanks for your reply... But which portion of code you need because i am not getting the error in any file.

Comment: I'm guessing this only occurred after you made some changes?

Comment: i just add the splash screen & icon file. but if i delete now, then also the error still come.

Answer (score 0):

Use debugger to check where crash is occurring. As you have not sHown any code,perhaps nobody would be able to help you on this clearly. in order to get full support you must have to post code where app is crashing and you are getting this error.

[Here is same error discussed in Apple Official Support Communities, also refer to this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3769128?start=0&tstart=0)

hope this helps